# Missing menu items

Tags: interface

Guys Im new and started some tutorials. However in the middle of one it tells me to select "Beza Circle" inside "Bevel Object". When I select "Bevel Object" there is nothing to select. Its just a blank pulldown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need two curve objects in your scene. One is used to define the shape of the bevel along the length of the other curve.

[image: sample curves]

Note that if you want a round bevel along the length of the curve you can use a bevel depth and resolution with a full fill setting under shape, while leaving the bevel object blank.